# Nil Error in Dev Environment but No Error in Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, development-environment, null

In the rails development environment on my local machine, I'm receiving the below 'nil' error message when accessing the 'financials' page of my app. Interesting thing is that in production, the 'financials' page is displayed correctly, without error.

After days of trial and error trying to see why the logged in vendor (user) is throwing up 'nil', here I am. I'm a bit green with programming so my hunch is that the development and production databases vary in some way, thus resulting in the 'nil' results for the vendor in the dev environment? Regardless, I'm not sure where to go from here.   Referenced files in the error message and development.rb are also included below.   Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Rails (3.2.17), Ruby (1.9.3 p545)

Error Message:

```
NoMethodError in Financials#income_statement 

Showing /home/vagrant/umarkit/app/views/financials/income_statement.html.erb where line #24 raised: 
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #24): 

21:   </tr>
22:   <tr><td class="lft"><%= t('financial_statements.revenues_html') %></td>
23:     <% @income_statemens.each do |incomestatement| %>
24:        <td class="lft"><%=number_to_financials(incomestatement.revenues)%></td>
25:     <% end %>
26:   </tr>
27:   <tr><td class="lft"><%= t('financial_statements.cogs_html') %></td>

Rails.root: /home/vagrant/umarkit

Application Trace: 

app/views/financials/income_statement.html.erb:24:in `block in app_views_financials_income_statement_html_erb___1058489885_86848080'
app/views/financials/income_statement.html.erb:23:in `each'
app_views_financials_income_statement_html_erb___1058489885_86848080'
app/controllers/financials_controller.rb:36:in `income_statement'
```

app/views/financials/income_statement.html.erb

```
<h1 class="sectionTitle">Income Statement</h1>

<div class="filterRange">
  <%= form_tag('/financials/income_statement', :method => 'get') do %>
  <label>Show Statement for:
    <%= select_tag 'year', options_for_select((@year-10)..(@year+5), @year) %>
  </label>
  <input type="submit" class="btn-showFilter" value="Show">
  <% end %>
</div>

<div class="filterState">
  <p>Showing Year: <%= @year %></p>
</div>
<% if !@income_statemens.nil? %>
<table class="utable">
  <tr><th class="lft nwp" width="350"><%= t('financial_statements.year_html') %></th>
    <% @income_statemens.each do |incomestatement| %>
       <th class="lft" width="534"><%=incomestatement.year%></th>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr><td class="lft"><%= t('financial_statements.revenues_html') %></td>
    <% @income_statemens.each do |incomestatement| %>
       <td class="lft"><%=number_to_financials(incomestatement.revenues)%></td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr><td class="lft"><%= t('financial_statements.cogs_html') %></td>
    <% @income_statemens.each do |incomestatement| %>
       <td class="lft"><%=number_to_financials(incomestatement.cogs)%></td>
    <% end %>
```

app/controllers/financials_controller.rb

```
class FinancialsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_vendor!

  # GET /financials
  # GET /financials.xml
  def index
    @vendor = current_vendor
    if @vendor != nil
      @financials = @vendor.get_financial_statements
    end

    if @financials == nil
      flash.now[:error] = "No transactions available."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @financials }
    end
  end

  def income_statement
    @vendor = current_vendor

    @year = params[:year] ? params[:year].to_i : Date.today.year

    puts @vendor.methods

    if @vendor != nil
      @income_statemens = @vendor.get_income_statement(@year)
      @income_statemens = @income_statemens.incomestatements
    end

    if @income_statemens == nil
      flash.now[:error] = "No transactions available."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @income_statemens }
    end
  end

  def balance_sheet
    @vendor = current_vendor

    @year = params[:year] ? params[:year].to_i : Date.today.year

    if @vendor != nil
      @balance_sheet = @vendor.get_balance_sheet(@year)
      @balance_sheet = @balance_sheet.balancesheets
    end

    if @balance_sheet == nil
      flash.now[:error] = "No transactions available."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @balance_sheet }
    end
  end

  def cash_flow
    @vendor = current_vendor

    @year = params[:year] ? params[:year].to_i : Date.today.year

    if @vendor != nil
      @cash_flow = @vendor.get_cash_flow(@year)
      @cash_flow = @cash_flow.cashflows
    end

    if @cash_flow == nil
      flash.now[:error] = "No transactions available."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @cash_flow }
    end
  end

  def show_transactions
    @vendor = current_vendor
    if @vendor != nil
      @transactions = @vendor.get_transactions
    end

    if @transactions == nil
      flash[:error] = "No transactions available, or First Date Stamp is nil."
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.xml  { render :xml => @entries }
    end
  end
end
```

development.rb

```
Ketch::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request.  This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the webserver when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
  config.whiny_nils = true

  # Show full error reports and disable caching
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Only use best-standards-support built into browsers
  config.action_dispatch.best_standards_support = :builtin

  # Devise Configuration
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }

  config.assets.debug = true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would test the hypothesis that the data differs as Rails uses different databases for development, testing, and production environments. Try resetting the underlying data and confirm.